# How to set up a variable = to a key in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I try to create a variable with the key of my local storage as it value.

i tried `let justId = localStorage.key`

but the response i got in the console is just `ƒ key() { [native code] }` and i'm not able to use it on my code

Could you help me with that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("whatever your key is")`

Comment: What makes you think `.key` *should* work?

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get and item or value from the `localStorage`, first you need to set a value.

```js
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// To get an item:
var result = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

The `localStorage.key` is used to get the `key` using the `value`

```js
localStorage.setItem('name', 'My Name')

var myKey = localStorage.key('MyName')
console.log(myKey)
// logs 'name'
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the key method expects an integer and returns the key at that index. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key): *The key() method of the Storage interface, when passed a number n, returns the name of the nth key in a given Storage object. The order of keys is user-agent defined, so you should not rely on it.*

Comment: Yes i understand that but my problem is that i have variable keys. My keys = the ID of the object in the local storage. I would like to create a variable =  these variable keys so i can use these keys with only one variable. I'm sorry i don't know if this is clear enough

Comment: Ok, I added a screenshort.

Comment: "The localStorage.key is used to get the key using the value" - This is completely wrong. The argument should be an index. Passing any non-numeric string is an incorrect use of the method and the result you see is only a coincidence.